# Method that prints text contained in a tsv file to console

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to print two methods that i have created but i cant figure out how to do it.

My project consists of Language.cs file in addition to Program.cs

This method in Language.cs:

```
public static void PrettyPrintAll(IEnumerable<Language> langs)
    {
        foreach (var printsAll in langs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(printsAll.Prettify());
        }
    }
```

Prints out this method that is also in Language.cs:

```
public string Prettify()
{
  return $"{Year}, {Name}, {ChiefDeveloper}, {Predecessors}";
}
```

this method prints out every query result (is also in Language.cs):

```
public static void PrintAll(IEnumerable<Object> sequence)
    {
        foreach (var prints in sequence)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prints);
        }
    }
```

Language class code other than the methods above:

```
namespace ProgrammingLanguages
{
public class Language
{
    public static Language FromTsv(string tsvLine)
    {
        string[] values = tsvLine.Split('\t');
        Language lang = new Language(
          Convert.ToInt32(values[0]),
          Convert.ToString(values[1]),
          Convert.ToString(values[2]),
          Convert.ToString(values[3]));
        return lang;
    }

    public int Year
    { get; set; }

    public string Name
    { get; set; }

    public string ChiefDeveloper
    { get; set; }

    public string Predecessors
    { get; set; }

    public Language(int year, string name, string chiefDeveloper, string predecessors)
    {
        Year = year;
        Name = name;
        ChiefDeveloper = chiefDeveloper;
        Predecessors = predecessors;
    }
```

All the methods are within the Language.cs file.
My issue is that i do not understand how to print them, i have tried in many ways but always get an error code The name 'PrintAll' does not exist in the current context or something like that.

In main this is how i have tried to call the method PrintAll:

```
var stringLanguage = languages.Select(languagePrint => $"{languagePrint.Year} 
{languagePrint.Name} {languagePrint.ChiefDeveloper}");

        PrintAll(stringLanguage);
```

Comment: Show us the class `Language`

Comment: @cid do you mean all of the code in the language class?

Comment: It seems like there is no method `Prettify()` in that class

Comment: Well, you need to place the method in the class

Comment: @Cid the second code block in the question is the prettify method

Comment: @cid all of this code are within language class. I might have been unclear about this

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your question, that's about `PrintAll()`

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: @Cid I updated the post with how i am calling the method at the bottom of the question

Comment: Is it called from main?

Comment: @cid yes it is called from main

Comment: This is a static method of the class `Language`, so you'll need to call it like this : `Language.PrintAll(stringLanguage);`

Comment: Thanks @cid can you post it as a solution so i can mark it as solved? I tried everything except the correct way to do this lol

Comment: Yes, sure, I'll add some explanations about why it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static` method `PrintAll()` belongs to the class `Language` and calling it from another class requier to prepend the class name first, such as `Language.PrintAll()`

```
public static void Main()
{
    // some code ...

    var stringLanguage = languages.Select(languagePrint => $"{languagePrint.Year} {languagePrint.Name} {languagePrint.ChiefDeveloper}");

    // PrintAll(stringLanguage); <-- This won't work because there is no method PrintAll() in the current class

    // This now refers to the correct class where the method belongs
    Language.PrintAll(stringLanguage);
}
```

Another way to do that would be to include the `static` part of the class `Language` in the class where `Main` is (I assume the class `Program`) :

```
// replace namespace by the correct namespace of the class
using static namespace.Language;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // some code ...

        var stringLanguage = languages.Select(languagePrint => $"{languagePrint.Year} {languagePrint.Name} {languagePrint.ChiefDeveloper}");

        // This now works because the static parts were imported
        PrintAll(stringLanguage); 
    }
}
```

However, I discourage using this, because this may lead to confusion